# Es6 Destructuring

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have a file that is similar to this:

```
const COLORS = {
  PRIMARY_COLOR: 'red',
  SECONDARY_COLOR: 'green'
};

const APP = {
  APP_COLOR: GRAY_DARK,
  APP_FONT_SIZE: FONT_SIZE_NORMAL,
  APP_FONT_WEIGHT: FONT_WEIGHT_NORMAL,
  APP_SEPARATOR_COLOR: GRAY_LIGHT
};

export default {
  ...COLORS,
  ...APP
};
```

The issue is when I'm trying to destructure that object from another file, I get undefined values?

```
import theme, { PRIMARY_COLOR } from '../../../themes/default';
```

printing the theme object works fine
but printing PRIMARY_COLOR gets undefined

Any help?

Comment: `Works fine`? What?

Comment: I got something similar to this:

{ APP_COLOR: '#000000', PRIMARY_COLOR: '#ff0000' }

Comment: I have added an answer to explain you the difference. See if it makes sense! :)

Comment: `import` does not do destructuring. It lets you import named exports, of which you have none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand the difference, you first need to know the way they are exported.

In case of `React`, the export goes something like this

```
const Component = ...
...
...
export Component;
```

This becomes available under `React.Component` and you can import it like `import { Component } from 'react';`

The way these look under the microscope is:

```
default.Component
...
```

While everything else is just under the `default` object.

If you do a quick `console.log` of `theme`, you'll understand what I mean.

I hope this makes sense.

---

Let's go a little in depth.

Suppose you have the following bit of code:

```
const a = {
    test: 'hello',
};

const b = {
    foo: 'bar',
}

export default a;
```

Now, let's `import` that

```
import * as theme from './test.js'
```

When we do a `console.log( theme )` we get

```
{ default: { test: 'hello' } }
```

What does this show? It means that the `export` object of a file contains a `default` property which is automatically loaded into memory when we do something like `import theme from 'test'`. However, if you have more than one `export`, the compiler gives you the option to pick and choose, but at the same time, provides you with a `default` object just for fall back.

In your case, you have exported everything under the `default`. When you do `import theme from './theme'` all works fine. However, when you do `{ PRIMARY_COLOR }...` it tries to find something which was exported like

```
export PRIMARY_COLOR...
```

I hope this makes it clear! :)

Answer (score 1):

The `{}` syntax in imports is for "named" imports and is not destructuring.

Just do this:

```
import theme from '../../../themes/default';

const { PRIMARY_COLOR } = theme;
```

Comment: but I used to do things like this and it works perfectly fine
Import React, { Component } from 'react';

can't figure out the difference

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli That's because React does both have named exports, as well as providing a default-exported object with all the named exports as properties (a horrible antipattern that leads to a lot of confusion).

Comment: Got it ... thank you very much for your help:))) .. and yes true ... kinda confusing really